# How to factor the denominator to fit a specific domain when using Laurent Series Expansion?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having some difficulty wrapping my head around the techniques used to perform the Laurent/Taylor series expansion, especially the factoring for a specific domain. Here is an example problem, and my thought process going forward:

Find the Laurent series expansion centered at $z=0$ of $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-2)}$ in each of the following domains.

(a) $|z|<1$

(b) $1<|z|<2$

(c) $|z|>2$

My first step for solving this problem is to use partial fraction decomposition of $f(z)$. $$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z+1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{3(z+1)}+\frac{2}{3(z-2)}$$

Next I attempt to expand both fractions on the right side. To do this, I need to factor/reorganize the denominator to meet my needs for a given domain. First let's attempt the first fraction in the domain $|z|<1$.

First, I think my goal is to put it in a form where I can use my knowledge of the geometric series. In addition to this, I want to account for my domain, I think this means I want the denominator in the form $(1-z)$:

$$\frac{1}{3(z+1)}=\frac{1}{3(1-(-z))}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^n$$

Next for the second fraction I have trouble factring for it to be in the same domain:

$$\frac{2}{3(z-2)}=\frac{2}{-6(1-\frac{z}{2})}\Rightarrow|\frac{z}{2}|<1\Rightarrow|z|<2$$

I can only get it to work for the domain $|z|<2$. I am also having trouble with the domain $1<|z|<2$ since I am not sure how to ensure it is between two points. Hopefully this question makes sense, and I hope I am correct in my understanding of the restrictions of the domain. Any help or advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do your geometric series differently depending on the domain.  For example, take the second of your partial fractions.  If $|z|<2$ then we have
$$\frac23\frac1{z-2}=-\frac13\frac1{1-\frac z2}=-\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Bigl(\frac z2\Bigr)^n\ .$$
If $|z|<1$ then $|z|<2$ and so *this still works* - this is the answer to the question at the beginning of your last paragraph.

If $|z|>2$ then the above does not work as the series diverges.  So do it this way:
$$\frac23\frac1{z-2}=\frac2{3z}\frac1{1-\frac2z}=\frac2{3z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Bigl(\frac2z\Bigr)^n=\frac23\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{z^{n+1}}\ .$$
The series converges because $|\frac2z|<1$.

For the other fraction you will need different series depending whether $|z|<1$ or $|z|>1$.  Notice that the latter includes $|z|>2$ as in your third region.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank your for pointing out the typo, it should be fixed now. I have a question, if $1-\frac{z}{2}$ is in the denominator, does that not imply $|\frac{z}{2}|<1$ which implies $|z|<2$? And $|z|<2$ does not always satisfy $|z|<1$, only the other way around right?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  The question is, does the geometric series converge?  And if $|z|<1$ then the answer is that the first series above does converge because the ratio of the geometric series is less than $1$.

Comment: I think I understand. I think my error before was I would use the denominator to imply the domain $|\frac{z}{2}|<1 \Rightarrow |z|<2$, but I am supposed to start with my domain and say $|z|<2 \Rightarrow |\frac{z}{2}|<1$ thus the series converges. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Sounds good.$\,$

Comment: Great, thank you for all your help!